# Print an escape code to a printer with PS (postscript) file

Tags: php, pdf, postscript

I'm dealing with a printer that can accept an escape code (i.e. printer command) printed as normal text.

For example, if I create a plain text file and write "~TR%10 10 20 20?" then print this, the printer recognize it as a command and doesn't print that bit of text on the paper.

When I try to do this via a postscript file (created from PHP using [PS module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ps.php)), I can't make the printer to recognize the same text as command. Instead it gets printed on paper.

Is there a PS command/format that I can use to ensure this bit of text is sent to the printer as is?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** I tried it with a PDF file as well (using PHP + [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org)), but had no luck either.

**UPDATE 2:** Adding sample code

```php
$ps = ps_new();

ps_open_file($ps, '/var/www/data/test.ps');

ps_set_info($ps, 'BoundingBox', '0 0 1011 638');
ps_set_info($ps, 'Orientation', 'Landscape');
ps_set_info($ps, "Creator", "PHP");
ps_set_info($ps, "Title", "Test");
ps_set_info($ps, "Keywords", "test");

ps_begin_page($ps, 1011, 638);
ps_set_parameter($ps, 'SearchPath', '/var/www/data/font');
$psfont = ps_findfont($ps, "ARIALN_0", "", 1); // Arial Narrow font
ps_setfont($ps, $psfont, 10.0);

ps_show_xy($ps, "ABC", 10, 10);
ps_show_xy($ps, "~TR%41 4 53 11?", 10, 50);

ps_end_page($ps);
ps_close($ps);
ps_delete($ps);

header('Content-type: application/postscript');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.ps"');

readfile('/var/www/data/test.ps');
```

Comment: can you give a PHP code example of what you have done?

Comment: @hek2mgl Edited with sample php code

Comment: Can you share the font for testing?

Comment: What printer is this, and what is the escape code for?

Answer (score 4):

Well I don't really know anything about PHP, but you certainly don't want to use `ps_show_x_y`. This undoubtedly maps to the postscript `show` operator whose job it is to display text on the printed page.

<del>From the docs, it looks like `ps_include_file` is the method you want.</del> Just write it straight to the file, bypassing all the ps_module stuff. And as Ken says, it should be before any other postscript code if you want the printer to recognize it. In particular, it will need to be before the magic number '%!' that the printer uses to detect a postscript program and enter the appropriate mode.

And of course, doing this will make the ps-file non-portable. gs, distiller, other printers, none of them will want to accept this as a postscript document.

As george mentions in a comment, whatever this control-code might do (which you haven't yet disclosed), might be available through the postscript side, too. The thing to do is to locate the PPD file for the printer (Postscript Printer Definition). This file contains postscript snippets to do printer-specific tasks. It's outfitted with heavy DSC comments and seemingly bizarre formatting to enable it to be parsed by program, but all this should make it easy to locate the snippet you need, assuming it is in fact available.

Comment: Nice answer! Though you also assume the printer does accept Postscript directly, which the O.P. does not assert. As it is the file might through an O.S. printer driver stack and be converted to a raster sequence to the printer. If that is the case, the only workaround is to send the control code to the printer **prior** to printing, bypassing the OS driver stack (else, it would be in another printing job)

Comment: This may not be viable for various reasons, but there's often a way to bypass the OS and connect to the printer "directly". Used to be, HP printers with JetDirect all listened on port 9100 IIRC. You could `telnet printer 9100 < doc.ps`. Or even `telnet printer 9100<enter>executive<enter><enter>`.

Comment: This is a user manual for the printer. [User manual](http://intraproc.com/downloads/Datacard/SD%20360%20%20SD%20260/Manual/539957-001_XPS__UserGuide.pdf)

Comment: On page 192, you can see some examples of the escape code. As some screenshots show, these escape code are just text written in a document. Also the Hints&Tips section on page 199 suggests not to use any character formatting. Probably this is where the problem lies with PDF/PS. Any ideas on how to suppress all formatting and just print plain text with PDF or PS?

Comment: Well, no. As far I can tell, it doesn't even make sense. Once the printer is in PS/PDF mode, it's not going to be scanning the same stream for its own codes. Are you sure this thing accepts postscript? I don't see anything about hacking these escapes into a ps document. Can you do a print-to-file to see what the driver output is. I bet its some kind of PCL but prolly not PS. It's whatever *that* format is that you need to hack these escapes into.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any way this is going to work. Your printer may be able to process random escape characters when its not interpreting PostScript, but it certainly won't be able to do so once you enter the PostScript interpreter.

This is because its perfectly possible to have binary data (which matches your escape character) in the body of a PostScript program. If the printer input handler processed that data instead, then the PostScript wouldn't work.

So you need to send you escape codes to the printer before the PostScript interpreter is started, or after it complete, you can't send it in the middle.

Comment: If you review your printer docs there <i>might be</i> implementation specific postscript commands to do whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @George you can use `*` *markdown-emphasis* `*` in comments, but no html. :(